# Error while running React native Android app in vs code

Tags: android, reactjs

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject> npm run android

> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
warn Failed to automatically start the packager server. Please run "react-native start" manually. Error details: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\scripts\.packager.bat'
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\right\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-06T03_29_02_350Z-debug.log
```

Comment: me too facing the same issue . have you got any fixes